# According to Catholicism, is our world the only one?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, creation, extra-terrestrial-life

Is this world the only one? Might God have created other worlds like this that are independent, having their own history? I don't mean another planet, but a whole other universe.

What would be the biblical bases for or against this possibility? What does Catholicism teach?

Comment: Also ask for LDS (mormon) perspective

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. Could you please explain?

Comment: I provided an answer, but I'd also like to get more info from you. What good is it for God to have made multiple universes?

Comment: There can't be another independent God because it wouldn't have the quality of all-powerful, all-knowing and so on. Only one can have these qualities.

Comment: Question simplified. Focused on the other universe.

Comment: This question is closely related God's omnipotence; several famous theologians/scientists of the High Middle Ages debated it; and even condemnations against the impossibility of multiple worlds were given. See Part 5 of [Duhem](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Pierre_Maurice_Marie_Duhem.aspx#1)'s [_Medieval Cosmology: Theories of Infinity, Place, Time, Void, and the **Plurality of Worlds**_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4757).

Comment: See also Paris [Bishop Étienne Tempier's 1277 Condemnations](https://isidore.co/misc/Res%20pro%20Deo/Condemnation%20of%201277/The%20Condemnation%20of%201277,%20God's%20Absolute%20Power,%20and%20Physical%20Thought%20in%20the%20Late%20Middle%20Ages%20(Edward%20Grant).pdf), esp. the condemned Prop. 27: “That the first cause cannot make more than one world." (cf. ch. 2, § "The Christian West", §§"Étienne Tempier" of [_Science Was Born of Christianity_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6066)).

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea, and we can't know apart from divine revelation, if our universe is the only one. The implications, however, indicate that this universe is the only universe.

Nothing in Scripture talks about multiple universes. It seems unnecessary for God to have made multiple universes (what purpose would it serve?), and I feel it would be dishonest for God to make another universe without telling us about it. God doesn't need to tell us everything He's doing, far from it, but I feel it would be dishonest.

Scripture claims there is no god like God (Ps 86:8, 1 Chr 17:20, 1 Ki 8:23, etc). I understand a god to be anything that is worshipped as most important. In that sense that are millions and even billions of gods. But as far as an entity that is wholly independent of everything else (which is what "I am that I am" means, in addition to other things), there is only 1 according to Scripture.

Comment: This reads like personal opinion. In particular, speculation about why God might choose to create more than one universe and whether or not it is dishonest to reveal that decision requires some support.

Comment: I offered what support I could. To address your issues would take several pages. To fully address it would take volumes. You're right, my opinion on why God created just one universe is weak.